Replacement newer image for fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0
I could see fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0 is being deprecated? What is the replacement newer image for the same?

From the documentation of fishtownanalytics/dbt docker page

DEPRECATED Please see GitHub Packages registry for all new images.
The Docker images contained here are for dbt up until 1.0.0 while any
newer images can be found at the following locations:
dbt-core:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pkgs/container/dbt-core⁠
dbt-bigquery:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery/pkgs/container/dbt-bigquery⁠
dbt-postgres:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pkgs/container/dbt-postgres⁠
dbt-redshift:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-redshift/pkgs/container/dbt-redshift⁠
dbt-snowflake:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/pkgs/container/dbt-snowflake⁠
dbt-spark:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-spark/pkgs/container/dbt-spark⁠
All dbt-labs packages:
https://github.com/orgs/dbt-labs/packages?visibility=public⁠

